# Empty textbox on button click by jquery in mvc3 viewpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page in mvc where I have 4 textbox with id and i want to clear the textbox on button click but my code does not seem to do any thing. Here's my piece of code:

```
<td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fdose, new { id = "pls", style = "width:100px;"            })%> </td>
<td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fduration, new { id = "plss", style =   "width:100px;" })%></td>     
<td> <button type="submit" class="t-button" name="med" value="med" id="clearmed">+</button></td>
```

And here's my script:

```
$("#clearmed").click(function (event) {
$("#plss").val("");
$("#pls").val("");
$("#abc").val("");
$("#abcd").val("");
 });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or any information as to why it is not working?

Comment: can you open the console in your browser (F12) and then run $("#plss").val(""); and see if it clears the textbox .. also just play with the console, see if $("#plss") and $("#pls") actually select something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a submit button, prevent the default behaviour of the submit button, on click. You can use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to do that. Also wrap your code in the ready event.

```
$(function(){
   $("#clearmed").click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#plss").val("");
       $("#pls").val("");
   });
}});
```

Comment: No the button also adds the textbox value to a grid aswell but at the same time it should clear the textbox aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using Firebug or a different browser debugger if you use something else.

Answer (score 0):

Without any errors, it's difficult to tell what may be going wrong. It would be best if you provided a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help out. If you do provide what error you are getting, I'll update my answer to be more specific to your problem.

I did run this through JSFiddle (see [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/XR9cD/1/)) and expanded out the ASP.NET helpers. You had an error in your HTML (which I believe you just fixed after seeing the edit), but there are no obvious bugs. I would look into your debugger (whether Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools or whatever) and *make sure jQuery is properly included*, that your text boxes are rendering how you expect, and that all the names are correct.

My final code:

```
<td><input id="pls" name="fdose" style="width:100px" type="textbox" /></td>
<td><input id="plss" name="fduration" style="width:100px" type="textbox" /><td>
<td><button type="submit" class="t-button" name="med" value="med" id="clearmed">+</button></td>​
```

and

```
$("#clearmed").on("click", function(event) {
    $("#plss").val("");
    $("#pls").val("");
});​
```